# Angular 2 - Remove element from object array according to one of its properties

Tags: angular

I'm trying to Remove an element from object array according to one of its properties, in Angular 2.

How can I implement the `removeItem` function so it will remove the `comment` object from the array **according to its id property** and thus remove it from the list ?

Here's the HTML template (loops with `ngFor` for all comments):

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of list">
     <button (click)="removeItem({{comment.id}})">delete</button>
     (... comment.... )
     ....
```

Here the Angular 2 code:

```
export class Comments {

    list =
        [new Comment(1, "text one", "koby", new Date("2015.01.02")),
         new Comment(2, "text two", "adim", new Date("2017.02.02")),
         new Comment(6, "text six", "asaf", new Date("2016.11.04"))
        ];

    addItem(val: string) {
        this.list.push(new Comment(3, "kokoko", "kobydo", new Date("2015.01.02")));
    }
    removeItem(id: number) {
        // How do I remove it from the array ?
    }
}

export class Comment {

    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public text: string,
        public creator: string,
        public date: Date
    ) { }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to use the interpolation:`(click)="removeItem(comment.id)"`

Comment: @developer033 What do you mean ?

Comment: It's just a tip because you used interpolation ( **{{ }}** ): `(click)="removeItem({{comment.id}})"`. In fact, you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks. I know - Just fixes it to removeItem( entry.id ) - Thank you so much. Have a great day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `.filter()` it:

```
removeItem(id: int) {
    this.list = this.list.filter(item => item.id !== id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jai. Have a great day.

Comment: You are welcome @KobyDouek. Glad this worked for you.